# Is there a surjection from $\mathbb N$ onto $\prod\limits_{n \in \mathbb N}I_n$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

**Definition:** A set $A$ is countable if it is finite or if there is a bijection $c: \mathbb N \to A$; otherwise it is uncountable.

> Let $I_n = \{i\in\mathbb N\mid i \leq n\}$. Then $\prod\limits_{n \in \mathbb N}I_n$ is uncountable.

This question arose when I tried to prove the above theorem.

I found that there exists an injection $\begin
{array}{l|rcl}
f : & \mathbb N
 & \longrightarrow & \prod\limits_{n \in \mathbb N}I_n \\
    & n & \longmapsto & f(n) \end{array}$

$f(n)$ is defined by
$f(n)(i)=\begin{cases}i & \text{ if } i<n\\
n & \text{ if } i \ge n
\end {cases}$

I'm not sure if there is a surjection from $\mathbb N$ onto $\prod\limits_{n \in \mathbb N}I_n$?

Comment: Why would there be a surjection?

Comment: There is a natural injection from $\{1,2\}^\mathbb{N}$ into your set, and the former set is uncountable. So the answer is No.

Comment: A subset of your set is $\{(0,x_1,x_2,\ldots) : x_j\in\{0,1\}\forall j\}$. From this set you get a surjection to the set of binary representations of the numbers in $[0,1)$.